# jQuery Ajax Call to asp.net webmethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Can any one say 
How we can specify a Success Function in Jquery Ajax call.
Suppose I have function like below `function

```
getComments(data,url,SucessFunction,FailurFunction) {

    var list = [data];
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ list: list });

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response, status) {
        var List = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
        $.each(List, function() {
            if (this['Cid'] != "1000")
                $('#' + ddlCities).append('<option value="' + this['Cid'] + '">' + this['CityCode'] + '</option>');
            else ($('#outerDiv').html(this['City']));

        });
    }
});
```

}
`

In this how can  define the success function ,error function

Like

```
getComments(data,url,SucessFunction,FailurFunction) {

var list = [data];
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ list: list });

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: SucessFunction

    }
});
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain,Why negative mark

Comment: http://encosia.com/simplify-calling-asp-net-ajax-services-from-jquery/ read this and all the articles over there you would find plenty of articles specifics to you needs, dun worry about -1 just neglect them

Comment: the link was good and is helpful.I found the required solution at the url:                                                http://derekreynolds.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/using-jquery-and-litjson-with-asp-net-passing-data-to-aspx/

Answer (score 0):

just for your ref: as per your needs

```
 AjaxPageMethod("your method", { " ": " " }, ajaxCallSuccess, ajaxCallFailure, "page name");

function ajaxCallSuccess(response) {
    var msg = response.d;
    $("tab").html(msg);
}

function ajaxCallFailure(response) {
    var msg = response.d;
}
```

function AjaxPageMethod(fn, reqObject, successFn, errorFn, aspxPage) {

```
    var dataObject = JSON.stringify(reqObject);

    //Call the page method
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: aspxPage + "/" + fn,
        contentType: "application/json;",
        data: "{'reqObject':" + dataObject + "}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFn,
        error: errorFn
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found using Web Method to be flaky, your might want to take a slightly different  approach, instead of using a webmethod, take a look at using ajax enabled WCF service?

Here is a blog post on how to set it up [using wcf to build fast and lean web apps](http://bob-the-janitor.blogspot.com/2009/12/using-wcf-to-build-fast-and-lean-web.html)